# I am not able to drag and drop in the objectAid plugin of the eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, uml

I have to generate UML diagrams from a project in java.
I am familiar with eclipse as well as intelliJ IDE.
I am not able to drag and drop in the objectAid plugin of the eclipse IDE.

Comment: This is not a question. Also, have you tried google?

Comment: Yeah jack thanks for the reply,
The reason why i was not able to drag and drop the classes and generate the class diagram was that my  project was in maven and the packages were not enumerated in eclipse.
Then this post helped me:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799710/imported-maven-project-does-not-appear-as-java-project-shows-folders).
Any way thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

In order to drag and drop in the objectAid plugin of the eclipseIDE and other IDE based on eclipse, you have to view your project as set of packages in explorer

[As shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQltj.png)

instead for viewing it as set of a simple folders